# Значение по умолчанию в поле HTML-формы

Tags: php, html

Как сделать, чтобы в заполняемом поле по умолчанию было значение и пользователь мог его стереть и написать свое?

Пока имею следующую заготовку:

```
<form name="name" method="post" action="sotr.php"> 
  <td align="center"><input type="text"  size='5' name="user" ></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Добавить" ></td>           
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="name" method="post" action="sotr.php"> 
 <td align="center"><input type="text"  name="user" value="Введите значение" onblur="if(value=='') value = 'Введите значение'" onfocus="if(value=='Введите значение') value = ''"></td>
 <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Добавить" ></td> 
</form>
```

Comment: В таком случае при фокусе на поле, значение по умолчанию будет удаляться, а если пользователь ничего не ввёл, то оно вернётся.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="name" method="post" action="sotr.php"> 
    <td align="center">
        <input type="text"  size='5' name="user" value="val">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    </td>
 </form>
```